python import different folder python file in linux/window, why result different?
Linux ubuntu 22.04 & python 3.10
windows 11 & python 3.11
this is my structure:
app/share
.
|-- A
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- tool.py
|-- B
|   `-- test.py

tool.py
def tool1():
    print("this is tool1")

test.py
from A.tool import tool1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tool1()

I run my Python file located in /app/share (Linux)
so my CMD is root@fdd6d308d5fc:/app/share# python3 B/test.py
and I got this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/share/B/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from A.tool import tool1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'A'

Even I using relative import from ..A.tool import tool1
it's still an error (ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package)
but!
I run the same structure in windows
CMD : PS D:\app\share> python B\test.py, and it's work
PS D:\app\share> python B\test.py
this is tool1

why is that and how can I fix it in Linux?
